# how to change functionality using correct way "you save 58%" and Rent "Rs.85" look below screenshot

Tags: product, configurable-product, custom-options, magento2.3.3, saving

[image]

It is possible to get using Custom option in simple product.
I tried

```
<?php // Display Discount percents start ?>
<?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
<?php $_savingPercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
    <p class="special-price yoursaving">
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Your Saving:') ?></span>
        <span class="price">
            <?php echo $_savingPercent; ?>%
        </span>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php // Display Discount percent end ?>
```

This code is showing only the $_finalPrice, $_price percentage.

I want to dynamically generate by selecting option like 30days, 90days...etc.

which is easy way to get the perfect value and also need this value in cart,order-details.

Answer (score 0):

$customOptions = $item->getProductOptions();

```
    foreach ($customOptions['options'] as $_eachOption) {
        // Value ID is stored in this field "option_value"
        $objModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')->load($_eachOption['option_value']);

        // This should provide all the details of this particular Option Value as chosen by the Customer when ordering this Product, but unfortunately it doesn't
        print_r($objModel->getData());

        /**
         * This gives the output as, without any details on Price and Price Type:-
         * Array
         * {
         *     [option_type_id] => 13014
         *     [option_id] => 4921
         *     [sku] => XBPS22
         *     [sort_order] => 0
         * }
         */

        unset($objModel);
    }
```

Comment: can you tell me where do i write code?

Comment: you need to pass this after checking the checkbox for every option

Comment: I have added another method for directly you can reach to that

Answer (score 0):

public function productFinalPrice($observer){
     $product    = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

```
 $productType=$product->getTypeID();

 if($productType == 'your_product_type')
 {

    $option = $product->getCustomOptions();
    $searchedOption = null;  

    //search for your option;
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {

        if($o->getTitle()=="your_attribute_title" && $o->getType()=="your_type_of_option(eg. area"){
            $optionId = $o->getOptionId();//got your searched optionId
            break;
        }
    }


    foreach($option as $key => $o) {
        if($key == "option_".$optionId) {
            $searchedOption = $o;
           //here you get the option object with the values in it
        }
    }


    $articleNumber = $searchedOption->getData('value'); // getthe value of your option


        //calculate final price like you need it
        $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
 }  
 return $this;
```

}

===========================

pass this function productFinalPrice

Comment: dont want to set final price i want to calculate rent and you save % on every product by option value.

Comment: ok not a big deal just calculate the %off by finalprice / product price * 100

Comment: but where do i get option value and calculate you save and rent and display him in frontend side?

Comment: $id = ( here you need to find out id of current id of product when you click any option like 30days, 90days etc );

$opt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load($id);